# How to make each element a list from zip() with list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, zip, tuples, list-comprehension

```
keys = zip([x for x in range(0, 10)], [x for x in range(0, 10)])
print keys
```

Result (A list with tuples):

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
```

How can I make each individual element a list, instead of tuples? The following example does not work:

```
keys = list(zip([x for x in range(0, 10)], [x for x in range(0, 10)]))
```

The following example does not work as well:

```
keys = zip([x for x in range(0, 10)], [x for x in range(0, 10)])
for i in keys:
    i = list(i)
print keys
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this list comprehension which converts the tuples `zip` yields into lists:

```
>>>keys = [list(t) for t in zip(range(10), range(10))]
>>>keys
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]
```

By the way `[x for x in range(0,10)]` is overkill, simply do `range(10)`

Another way without list comprehension would be: `map(list, zip(range(10), range(10)))` but with Python 3 this won't return a list, it'll return a `map` object instead.